# Fancybox 2 how to trigger a _top target url from child image

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using Fancybox 2 to open a simple splash lightbox image from a thumbnail. I'd like to the user to click the resulting lightbox image and trigger an href to a new page "_top". How does this get added to the Fancybox Javascript?

Comment: what you want if user click on image the new tab should open a link?

Comment: I figured it out. it's done by wrapping the image after the callback.